# Keras_ocr - Failed to recognize_from_boxes

Tags: python, keras, ocr

I am working with the keras_ocr recognizer and I want it to scan only inside the bounding boxes which I already selected. The API supports this kind of opperation with `recognize_from_boxes`  Just so you know: [keras_ocr documentation](https://keras-ocr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#keras_ocr.recognition.Recognizer.recognize_from_boxes).

```
#Parameters
#images – A list of input images, supplied as numpy arrays with shape (H, W, 3).
#boxes – A list of groups of boxes, one for each image

#Recognizer_ = Recognizer_.recognize_from_boxes(images = img_list, box_groups= bb_list)
```

I send to the function two arguments, the first one is the list of images as a numpy array:

[image: img_list print]

And secondly, I send the list of bounding boxes:

[image: bb_list print]

The problem I get is a type error, `TypeError: object of type 'int' has in len()`, stating that the type entered is invalid. I would like to understand more about the error and a possible solution. The print related to the error call:

[image: bb_list print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In API documentation it mentions that `box_groups` should be `A list of groups of boxes, one for each image` which means it assumes there might be many boxes in a single image but your input is only `a list on boxes`. If you have only one box per image then you can do it this way -

```py
# reshape bb_list from (N, 4) -> (N, 1, 4)
Recognizer_ = Recognizer_.recognize_from_boxes(images = img_list, 
                                            box_groups= np.expand_dims(bb_list, axis=1))
```